# Why is Vue algolia instant search producing"Unexpected token 'export'" when I import state mappings or router

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, algolia, quasar-framework

I'm using algolia instant search in my vue js application running on the quasar framework in ssr mode. I want to do routing in my application with the instant searching widgets. Docs are detailed [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/routing-urls/vue/).

I'm following the instructions, which are very simple. I import the following:

```
import { history as historyRouter } from 'instantsearch.js/es/lib/routers';
import { singleIndex as singleIndexMapping } from 'instantsearch.js/es/lib/stateMappings';
```

Then in my data I init the routing objects:

```
data() {
  return {
    searchClient: algoliasearch(
      "",
      ""
    ),
    routing: {
      router: historyRouter(),
      stateMapping: singleIndexMapping("instant_search"),
    },
  };
},
```

After this point, if I try and refresh my page I get the following error pointing back to the stateMappings import and routing imports:

```
Unexpected token 'export'
Open: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js
Unable to locate file source.
```

I'm fairly certain this is due to running my vue quasar app in `ssr` mode but the interesting thing is I am explicitly running algolia on the client only as specified in my quasar.conf.js file and wrapping the component I wrote that runs algolia instant search in the `<q-no-ssr>` tag:

```
    boot: [
        'axios',
         {path: 'algolia', server: false},
    ],
```

```
 <q-no-ssr>
    <SearchComponent :numHits="4" :homePage="true" />
 </q-no-ssr>
```

How can I utilize the algolia instant search routing, history, and state mappings this way?

Answer (score 1):

I did get the same error when using Algolia with Nuxt (so not using quasar).

What the resolved the issue for me was making sure that the dependencies are transpiled correctly in the nuxt config:

```
 build: { 
   transpile: ['vue-instantsearch', 'instantsearch.js/es'], 
 },
```

Maybe a similar action has to be taken in order to make it work for quasar?